# ComboBox: disable DropDown on click

Tags: c#, wpf

I want DropDown to appear only if user clicks on arrow and input to still work as TextBox. 
I have tried:

```
private void MyComboBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
   Point pos = Mouse.GetPosition(cb); 
   if (pos.X < cb.ActualWidth - 25) e.Handled = true;
}
```

This works, but clicking in the middle of the text does not set cursor position since it is already handled. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just want to make the `ComboBox` editable.

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"/>
```

This will allow users to enter text into the TextBox portion of the control, and will only display the drop-down portion of the control when they click the small triangle / down arrow.

Comment: I have found that the other part was my mistake in ComboBox style having button are under the whole ComboBox. Thanks!